# Can I run EditorConfig over C# Files From the Command Line?

Tags: c#, code-cleanup, editorconfig

Newer versions of Visual Studio Support EditorConfig within the IDE which is useful, however it would be best if I could run it from the command line (and therefore in automation).

Is there any stand alone tool that supports all of the EditorConfig Settings as the Visual Studio IDE does? [Microsoft Docs: .NET coding convention settings for EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference?view=vs-2017)

Here's what I have found so far:

- [ReSharper CleanupCode Command-Line Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/CleanupCode.html) - It is unclear if this supports editorconfig, there is some mention in the [resharper documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Using_EditorConfig.html#roslyn) but it is unclear if this is supported by the stand alone tool.
- [dotnet/codeformatter](https://github.com/dotnet/codeformatter) - This for sure does not support editorconfig and according to [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/codeformatter/issues/267) the project is dead

Baring a stand alone tool is there any way to force Visual Studio into running the code cleanup "headless"? That might be my only solution.

Answer (score 8):

I've been hunting for the same thing, just found a *very* new tool for this, `dotnet-format`, put out from the Roslyn team:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Tools/dotnet-format

From their README:

> `dotnet-format` is a code formatter for `dotnet` that applies style preferences to a project or solution. Preferences will be read from an `.editorconfig` file, if present, otherwise a default set of preferences will be used.

Looks like the indented usage is something like:

```
$ dotnet format -w MyApplication.sln
```

Comment: for .Net Core 5
1: dotnet tool install -g dotnet-format, then
2: dotnet-format -w

Comment: `dotnet format --verify-no-changes --include SomeFiles.cs` takes around 4 seconds for a single file. Thanks you, Microsucks.